# Wordpress mysql deos not work with php7

Tags: php, mysql

i have a vps with this specs :
CPU Model: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
CPU Details: 4 Core (2200 MHz)
Distro Name: CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
Memory RAM : 8 GB

i am running Centos web panel on it, i have two wordpress websites , one (which has the problem i think ) has over 30000 posts, and the other has 6000 posts.

when i run the server on php5.6 every thing goes well but the cpu load is high, and when i  upgrade it to php7 CPU load became lower and nice for about 8 hours and suddenly a ***Query*** run and CPU load became 100% and my websites go down.
i do not know why , i tried a lot of solutions but nothing happened. can any one please help!!

The Query :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjdhT.jpg
My Active plugins : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdT97.jpg
Theme : Publisher Version   7.6.0

- i am using the same theme and plugins on both websites , but only the one with 30000 posts is making the problem.

Comment: Why are you running both All-in-1 WP Security & WordFence? Can you post the server error logs? What happens when you disable all plugins? Lastly, could you upgrade to 7.2 instead of php 7.0? & what version of MySQL are you using? 5.7 should be fine

Comment: i am just using All-in-1 WP Security recently, when the problem happened i was not using it.
- i didn't disable all plugins before, i think thousands are using the same plugins
- yes i installed php 7.2 and tried 7.3 also nothing happened.

Database info : 
Server version :  5.5.5-10.1.41-MariaDB
Client version :  mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev

Comment: Thousands may be using those plugins, but maybe not at the versions and in the environment you are. Just start fresh. Make a backup of the database & wp-content folders. Turn off all plugins, switch to default theme. Then turn plugins on one by one. Stick with php7.2 as 7.3 has some changes that plugins might not be ready for yet.